# How to make a variable string containing buttons

Tags: android

I want make a layout like this [image: linked image].

Initially we arranged buttons and text in succession.
However, if there is a line break, it will not be displayed as desired.
Do you know the library or the means to realize this?
My English is still not so good, though, Sorry.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please show your code.

Comment: Jon Goodwin
Thank you very much.

There is no source code yet, it will be implemented from now on.
I can see only the position where the text and the button are displayed when it works.
It is necessary to make a layout dynamically from that information.

Answer (score 0):

```
String str="text1 button1 text2 button2 etc.";
SpannableString spanString=new SpannableString(str);
//You can use SpannableStringBuilder also

ClickableSpan buttonSpan1 = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do something
            }
        };
ClickableSpan buttonSpan2 = new ClickableSpan() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // Do something
            }
        };
spanString.setSpan(
                buttonSpan1,
                str.indexOf("button1"),
                str.indexOf("button1") + String.valueOf("button1").length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
spanString.setSpan(
                buttonSpan2,
                str.indexOf("button2"),
                str.indexOf("button2") + String.valueOf("button2").length(),
                Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Comment: Naveen
Thank you very much.

Your solution will likely solve the problem.